# Labelling LiDAR points in Python

Tags: lidar, las

I am new working with LiDAR and have been assigned to label LiDAR points. I have no clue where to start. Is there any Python library that helps in this task?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We use a Focused question/Best answer model for problem solving. We are not a tutorial site, and aren't well suited to making recommendations for a way to start work. Once you have identified a path, we will be better able to help you.